# Rotation doesn't work correctly - webview

Tags: android, mobile, webview

I created the code following the android documentation guidelines developer, but the code is apparently correct but to turn the mobile screen it does not behave the way it should is rotate the screen and continue in the same state it was in when them instead he comes back to the home page. There is something wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.uol.com.br");
}


@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
}
@Override
protected void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestart");
}
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
}
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    wv.saveState(outState);
    Log.i(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState");
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG,"onRestoreInstanceState");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, it's seems to work just fine.  You are saving and restoring the webview state correctly, so the webview picks up right where the user was before the rotation.

One thing though, clicking on any link on the webpage you load will open in the default browser, NOT your app.  Maybe that's related to the issue you are seeing?

Add this to your onCreate() to allow pages to open within your app:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did as suggested but still does not work on my phone, I'm using a LG L90 . In android studio running log appear two warnings will it relates to the non-functioning of the rotation. E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus.

E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

Comment: I'd suggest trying your code on another device and/or emulator.  Find out if it's something specific to your LG.  Maybe the webview needs to be updated?